# Intermittent error with apache and svn: Error reading chunk (overflow)

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

We recently started seeing intermittent errors in our apache logs (version 2.2.22 32bit) when trying to access our SVN repository (version 1.7.8 32bit):

**(20014) Internal error: Error reading chunk (overflow)**

The SVN repository is currently weighing in at around 44 GB / 168,351 Files / 177 Folders.

I'm running a `svnadmin verify` on the repository but at its current rate it's going to take a few days.

Is there way to get more detailed logs from either apache or svn?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by disabling Kapersky's virus protection.